# Why doesn't the java process exit after kill -15?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, kill, kill-process

I kill the java programm by `kill -15 $PID`, and from the log I find the `ShutdownHook` is called and finished. But the process is still running.

So I dump the threads and find most of the are daemon thread, but the following:

```
[xiafei.qiuxf@dwbasis130009 tesla]$ grep prio stack  | grep -v daemon
"DestroyJavaVM" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab072000 nid=0x79d3 waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000041da4000]
"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab112000 nid=0x79e6 runnable 
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab105800 nid=0x79d4 runnable 
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab106800 nid=0x79d5 runnable 
"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab107000 nid=0x79d6 runnable 
"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab107800 nid=0x79d7 runnable 
"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab108000 nid=0x79d8 runnable 
"Gang worker#5 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab109000 nid=0x79d9 runnable 
"Gang worker#6 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab109800 nid=0x79da runnable 
"Gang worker#7 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10a000 nid=0x79db runnable 
"Gang worker#8 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10a800 nid=0x79dc runnable 
"Gang worker#9 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10b800 nid=0x79dd runnable 
"Gang worker#10 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10c000 nid=0x79de runnable 
"Gang worker#11 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10c800 nid=0x79df runnable 
"Gang worker#12 (Parallel GC Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10d000 nid=0x79e0 runnable 
"Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab111000 nid=0x79e5 runnable 
"Gang worker#0 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10e800 nid=0x79e1 runnable 
"Gang worker#1 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10f000 nid=0x79e2 runnable 
"Gang worker#2 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab10f800 nid=0x79e3 runnable 
"Gang worker#3 (Parallel CMS Threads)" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab110800 nid=0x79e4 runnable 
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab118000 nid=0x79f1 waiting on condition
```

It seems that they are GC threads or jvm's threads, but none of them is mine(my threads are all finished.), so why the jvm process still keeps running?

Answer (score 3):

The dump says:

```
"DestroyJavaVM" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaaab072000 nid=0x79d3 
    waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000041da4000] <<------------
```

That means the process to terminate the application can't proceed because someone owns the monitor `0x0000000041da4000`.

Look through the dump to find out which thread owns this monitor. That should give you an idea how to proceed.